# Query returns multiple records

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I've a problem with a query that returns multiple value using Spring 3.

I'm using this to retrieve values, but the `TemplateFlow` objects returned from DB are always null (all field contains `null` or default value).

```
List<TemplateFlow> flows = (List<TemplateFlow>) getJdbcTemplate().query(
   sqlString, 
   ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(TemplateFlow.class)
);
```

`TemplateFlow` is a class that contains all field. I'm retrieving some values after an update, is it possible I need to commit the changes? (but I'm not using any kind of transaction).

```
public class TemplateFlow {

    private int id_templateflow;
    private int id_templateprocess;

    public int id_templateflow() { return this.id_templateflow; }
    public void id_templateflow(int id_templateflow) { this.id_templateflow = id_templateflow; }    

    public int id_templateprocess() { return this.id_templateprocess; }
    public void id_templateprocess(int id_templateprocess) { this.id_templateprocess = id_templateprocess; }

}
```

I I try to run the query directly on DB it returns two rows.

thanks for help!
Andrea

Comment: What happens when you run that query in the query tool of your database with the parameters you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TemplateFlow` class does not conform to the javabean pattern, and [`ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.html) requires this to be the case:

> Column values are mapped based on matching the column name as obtained from result set metadata to public setters for the corresponding properties.

For example, you should have

```
int getId_templateflow()
void setId_templateflow(int)
```

instead of

```
int id_templateflow()
void id_templateflow(int)
```

However, I'd advise against using `ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper` at all - it couples your database too tightly to your code, and that's not a good thing. Consider instead writing your own implementation of `RowMapper`.

Comment: Hi, yeah! I create my own RowMapper class and call in that way: List<TemplateFlow> flows =  getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlString,new TemplateFlowRowMapper());